# MacOS Override App Shortcut

Tags: macos

I can't seem to override Acrobat reader's default shortcuts.

I thought the problem was the fact that the menu item was nested, but the overrides also don't work for top level items.

[image: menu bar]

[image: shortcut pref]

Comment: It doesn't really surprise me with anything Adobe. Most of their apps have their own Shortcuts pref page… though Acrobat doesn't seem to have.

Comment: I assume you have tried to go into System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > Adobe Reader?